# error occurrance while validating HRESULT = '80004005'

Tags: windows-services, setup-project

i have created a windows service in visual studio c#.net ,and i am trying to create a set up and deployment for the service, when i am buiding the  windows service project ,it is successful

i have added the  Project Output Group as  Primary Output with windows service project.
i have also added the custom action to the set up project,

when i try to build the set up project it displays"An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80004005'"  i also noted there is nothing in the  detected dependencies folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the error code `8000000A`, so it might be different, and I'm not sure if this is any help for your problem.  But re-adding references did not work for me. However, what worked for me was removing the `.suo` file (next to the `.sln`) and (re)building again.

(It might have been caused by accidentally opening a Visual Studio 2010 class library in a Visual Studio 2008 comapct project.  I am not even going to try reproducing this!)

Removing the `.suo` will make you 'loose' your open files (and maybe some other settings?), but IMHO that's just a small sacrifice(?).

I just hope this will save someone some time...

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly the same issue with a WinForms project. I had several projects in my solution, they would all build without an issue except for the set up project.

I overcame this by removing all the references to the other projects in the solution in the main project (the one that was being set as primary output) and then re-adding them again by going to add reference >> project. Once I had re-added the references to the other projects in the solution, the project dependencies re-appeared and all built fine.

Hope that helps

Richard